# Uploading a file with s3manager

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3

I'm trying to download a few files from my website and upload them to amazons3.

Here is my code:

```
import (
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/credentials"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/session"
    "github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3/s3manager"
)

func main() {
    // Make a GET request to an image to be downloaded and uploaded to s3
    resp, err := http.Get("http://my-site.com/image.jpg")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Get the AWS credentials
    creds := credentials.NewSharedCredentials("/Users/name/.aws/credentials", "default")

    // Set up config
    config := &aws.Config{
        Region:      aws.String("US Standard"),
        Credentials: creds,
    }

    // Set up a new AWS session
    sess := session.New(config)

    // Set up a new s3manager client
    uploader := s3manager.NewUploader(sess)

    result, err := uploader.Upload(&s3manager.UploadInput{
        Body:   resp.Body,
        Bucket: aws.String("mimi-movies"),
        Key:    aws.String("mimi.jpg"),
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln("Failed to upload", err)
    }

    log.Println("Successfully uploaded to", result.Location)
}
```

I keep getting a run time error of a nil pointer dereference the error doesn't help much but for some reason I think it might have to do with ssl but here is the entire error:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal 0xb code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x236ffe]

goroutine 1 [running]:
panic(0x4743c0, 0xc82000a0e0)
    /usr/local/Cellar/go/1.6/libexec/src/runtime/panic.go:464 +0x3e6
github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3.validateSSERequiresSSL(0xc820066380)
    /Users/name/work/src/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3/sse.go:15 +0x17e
github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/request.(*HandlerList).Run(0xc820066478, 0xc820066380)
    /Users/name/work/src/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/request/handlers.go:136 +0xc3
github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/request.(*Request).Build(0xc820066380, 0x0, 0x0)
    /Users/name/work/src/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/request/request.go:189 +0x69
github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/request.(*Request).Sign(0xc820066380, 0x0, 0x0)
    /Users/name/work/src/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/request/request.go:210 +0x31
github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/request.(*Request).Send(0xc820066380, 0x0, 0x0)
    /Users/name/work/src/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/aws/request/request.go:261 +0x6f4
github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3/s3manager.(*uploader).singlePart(0xc8201520f0, 0x8bb980, 0xc82014a030, 0xc82000a140, 0x0, 0x0)
    /Users/name/work/src/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3/s3manager/upload.go:449 +0x1fc
github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3/s3manager.(*uploader).upload(0xc8201520f0, 0xc8201520f0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /Users/name/work/src/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3/s3manager/upload.go:355 +0x563
github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3/s3manager.Uploader.Upload(0x500000, 0x5, 0x0, 0x2710, 0xe00240, 0xc820156018, 0xc82016e000, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, ...)
    /Users/name/work/src/github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/service/s3/s3manager/upload.go:329 +0x15a
main.main()
    /Users/name/work/src/gitlab.com/user/project/test/main.go:39 +0x59f
exit status 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a bug on the aws-go-sdk but the solution is to change the region to "us-east-1"

```
// Set up config
config := &aws.Config{
    Region:      aws.String("us-east-1"),
    Credentials: creds,
}
```

Comment: v1.1.30 of the SDK should of fixed the panic with https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-go/commit/cfbcfdb10ed6e2dd2f6b81f50e259e616d4d3f34, and now should return an error when making the request.  If you're still experiencing this issue with the latest version of the SDK please file a issue.

Answer (score 4):

As @user3666882 mentioned there's bug in aws-go-sdk and you should probably check your region.

In your code, you have written code to get AWS Credential.

```
// Get the AWS credentials
    creds := credentials.NewSharedCredentials("/Users/name/.aws/credentials", "default")
```

You might try this in your terminal :

> aws configure

And configure your aws-sdk.

Else you can use Minio. But your have to put your ACCESS_KEY_ID and SECRET_ACCESS_KEY in your code, which is very bad for production use.

```
 s3Client, err := minio.New("s3.amazonaws.com", "YOUR-ACCESSKEYID", "YOUR-SECRETACCESSKEY", false)
```

Also, you can use external API [Viper](https://github.com/spf13/viper) to hide these keys. But I recommend you to use official AWS SDK for Go.

Comment: just put them in an env variable and load them via os.GetEnv

Answer (score 0):

You could have alternatively used [Minio-go](https://github.com/minio/minio-go) client libraries, its Open Source & compatible with AWS S3.

Here is a simple example to [Put an object](https://github.com/minio/minio-go/blob/master/examples/s3/putobject.go)

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/minio/minio-go"
)

func main() {
    // Note: YOUR-ACCESSKEYID, YOUR-SECRETACCESSKEY, my-testfile, my-bucketname and
    // my-objectname are dummy values, please replace them with original values.

    // Requests are always secure (HTTPS) by default. Set insecure=true to enable insecure (HTTP) access.
    // This boolean value is the last argument for New().

    // New returns an Amazon S3 compatible client object. API compatibility (v2 or v4) is automatically
    // determined based on the Endpoint value.
    s3Client, err := minio.New("s3.amazonaws.com", "YOUR-ACCESSKEYID", "YOUR-SECRETACCESSKEY", false)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    object, err := os.Open("my-testfile")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    defer object.Close()

    n, err := s3Client.PutObject("my-bucketname", "my-objectname", object, "application/octet-stream")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
    log.Println("Uploaded", "my-objectname", " of size: ", n, "Successfully.")
}
Status API Training Shop Blog About
```

Hope it helps.

Disclaimer: I work for [Minio](https://minio.io)